# Average SumIf, differentiate between Zero and Blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need some help from the almighty community here.

I have a sample set of data here. I am trying to sumif some data and then average it. the goal being to get a running average of my budget but only take into account months that have happened already.

For example, I use "Spending" in the spreadsheet, but it could be anything: Gas, Home Improvement, etc. Say in January I spend $600 on Spending well then my average for the year is $600. But then say in February I spend nothing on Spending, then my average is $300. My problem, I seem to only be able to get an average for all months regardless if they happened, so it currently is the month of February, March - December get taken into account in the average because they all have blank numbers, resulting in an inaccurate average. What I want is for it to calculate the average as the months go on.

The only other caveat, is I use categories in my spreadsheet, in my example I have Spending category and then a notes column for what I spent it on. This is because I do category averages and totals at the end of the year and I like to know what each item was.

I tried using "" to distinguish between Blanks and 0s, but if you try to average "", its text and i get an error. See in Cell M5. M5 is where I am trying to get 900 as the average because January and February have happened but December has not.

[Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/file/d/1lmhnlg27lRHOL_HjVYMsEIze_AYOut9n/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel)

Comment: Add a section to your query ignoring empty but not zero values, maybe?

Comment: There are a lots of ways to solve this. What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck? You say you are using sumif, what about using averargeifs with some kind of date critera also.

Comment: @gns100 if you look at the spreadsheet. The first thing I need is for the formula to add up all of the instances of Shopping in each month. And then average ONLY the months that have happened even if one of the months that’s already happened is zero

Comment: @music2myear I don’t use query. Always scared me. So I’m not sure how to ignore blanks but not zeroes. However again to my above comment to GNS100. If the month has happened and there’s no shopping for example I need that blank to be assumed as a zero for the calculation of the average.

Comment: Why link to a file if there's only about 5 cells filled with data to reproduce.
Better post a table using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables that would also help future visitors with a similar question to recognize the problem and possibly it's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

```
=SUM((MONTH(A1)<MONTH(TODAY()))*SUMIF(A3:A5,J4,C3:C5),
(MONTH(D1)<MONTH(TODAY()))*SUMIF(D3:D5,J4,F3:F5),
(MONTH(G1)<MONTH(TODAY()))*SUMIF(G3:G5,J4,G3:I5))/
((MONTH(A1)<MONTH(TODAY()))+(MONTH(D1)<MONTH(TODAY()))+
(MONTH(G1)<MONTH(TODAY())))
```

You should avoid using `AVERAGE` function when your data are calculated and not in cells.
If you have a new version of Excel (365) you can also try a shorter version:

```
=LET(n, MATCH(TODAY(),VSTACK(A1,D1,G1)),
SUM(TAKE(VSTACK(SUMIF(A3:A5,J4,C3:C5),
SUMIF(D3:D5,J4,F3:F5),SUMIF(G3:G5,J4,G3:I5)),n))/n)
```

Comment: this works! i will admit its less pretty than i expected but it works. i am going to run this out for a full year or 12 months, so this is about to get really long. but it works and i can go with it. If anyone has another solution i'd love to see it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the purpose of the (MONTH(A1)<MONTH(TODAY())) before each SUMIF?

Comment: As `TODAY()` may be any date this is to decide which `SUMIF` is taken into account in the calculations.

Comment: see now. Thank you for your help. I used your solution as my basis. I considered this solved.